# Como usar o SAS Enterprise Guide para trabalhar com amostras complexas?

Tags: sas

Preciso modelar dados do PNAD - IBGE, que utiliza plano amostral complexo. É possível utilizar o SAS Enterprise Guide nessa modelagem?

Comment: Talvez seja porque eu não entendo nada de estatística, mas a pergunta parece bem ampla. Tem como deixá-la um pouco mais focada?

Comment: Eu não sei se é possível com o Enterprise Guide (eu nunca usei), mas é possível usando Survey Procedures usando programação SAS. Por exemplo, com `PROC SURVEYMEANS` você pode fazer uma série de inferências descritivas, e com `PROC SURVEYREG` ajustar modelos de regressão, entre outras procedures.